# Вопрос Zyxel-Cisco и vlan

Tags: cisco, vlan

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос следующий, на объекте локальная сеть построена по следующему маршруту, zyxel ES 3148 и далее по маршруту четыре свича Cisco SF302-08P. Было создано два vlan - одна офис, вторая арендаторы. С zyxel'a настроен тегированный трафик и второй свич после него тоже, все остальные циско не тегированные,и все работает, если везде поставить тегированый трафик то работает тоже (все порты прихода и уход транковые). На циско офисный влан настроен на дефолтном vlan1 и vlan100 для арендаторов. Вопрос в следующем,на сколько корректно использовать дефолтный vlan1 на циско и стоит ли тегировать пакеты, когда работает в и том и в том случае. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать дефолтный vlan0 в принципе корректно, ничего страшного не произойдет, а вот тегирование я бы посоветовал делать. Пока всего два vlan проблем без него может не возникнуть, но когда придется расшириться и ввести новые vlan, то тегирование избавит от геммороя с определением к какой vlan принадлежит трафик. но это чисто мое ИМХО и как бы я сделал. Вам же лучше видно на месте - будет ли расширяться сеть и т.д